# Polymer 2.x - adding bindings dynamically (vs using binding annotations)

Tags: polymer-2.x

Can we add bindings dynamically (in JS code) or are the binding annotations the only way to specify bindings?

Edit: It looks like there was something added to Polymer 2.0 to support this.

This is a method on Polymer element:
protected static addPropertyEffect(property: string, type: string, effect: Object=)
Inherited from Polymer.PropertyEffects

Comment: Thanks to @Niklas for pointing me to the thread that got me the answer. See the Aug 14th comment on this issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3456

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about creating an Element that makes use of data-binding. Or just adding data-binding to an existing element inside your DOM ?
Either way I don't think this is possible or at least not recommended to do.
I did however come across a similar git issue with an answer including a demo. [Answer by AliMd](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1778) Maybe this can help you but as mentioned above I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting as an answer:

It looks like there was something added to Polymer 2.0 to support this.

This is a method on Polymer element: protected static addPropertyEffect(property: string, type: string, effect: Object=) Inherited from Polymer.PropertyEffects

Comment: Do you have a link or example ?

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/mixins/Polymer.PropertyEffects and https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/blob/master/ep13-08-first-look/bower_components/polymer/src/features/standard/effects.html.